# Getting response from dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to give each button different value so when someone clicks the button I would know which button was clicked by the value it had. Since there were a lot of values I got the data from the database and created the buttons dynamically.

Problem:
I wanted to test if the php block was successful so I checked by Inspect element and I got the right values for each button but I do not know how to get a specific action from a dynamically generated button.

```
<?php
            while($course = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)){
                echo "<p>".$course['course_title']."</p>";
                echo "<p>".$course['course_code']."</p>";
                echo "<button value=".$course['id']. " id='submitbt' name='submitbt'>Select</button>";  
            }
        ?>
```

I have tried using this to know if the click event works but it only works for the first button. It does not work for other buttons.

```
$("#submitbt").click(function(){
            alert(this.value);
        });
```

Comment: id **must be unique**, then you have to use event delegate in JS / jQuery

Comment: If I make id unique by adding numbers and the end of submitbt1,submitbt2... then how can I refer to each button using Javascript/ Jquery?

Comment: @MrJ got it thanks

Comment: As i said you have to use event delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use the same id property for multiple elements, you can only use each id once.

Change your button markup to this.

```
echo "<button value=".$course['id']. " class='submitbt' name='submitbt'>Select</button>";
```

and then in your jQuery you can write.

```
$(".submitbt").click(function(){
    // do something
});
```

Notice that the jQuery uses .submitbt to reference all elements which have the class .submitbt